# f90 read .txt file return NaN

Tags: arrays, fortran, nan, fortran90, readfile

I am trying to read a .txt file with multiple arrays with a fortran program.

It looks like the program is finding the file but it only returns NaN value...

```
 !
INTEGER                              :: T, RH, i, j, ierror
!
REAL, DIMENSION(3,3)                 :: AFILE
!
LOGICAL                              :: dir_e

inquire(file='PSR_FAB.txt', exist=dir_e)

if ( dir_e ) then
 print*, "dir exists!"
else
 print*, 'nope'
end if

OPEN (UNIT = 1234 , FILE = 'PSR_FAB.txt', STATUS = 'OLD', ACTION = 'READ')

   DO i=1,3
      READ(1234,*, IOSTAT=ierror) (AFILE(i,j),j=1,3)
       print*, (AFILE(i,j),j=1,3)
!      if (ierror>0) then
!        stop 'Error while reading from file. '
!      elseif (ierror<0) then
!        print* ,PSR_FILE
!        stop 'Reached end of file. '
!      endif
   ENDDO
  CLOSE(UNIT=1234)
!
T=2
RH=3
print*,AFILE(T,RH)
!
```

In order to test the program, I'm using the following .txt file:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Also, when I am using the "ierror if test", the "Reaching end of file" pops out, which mean ierror<0, which mean the end of file is reach.

At first I thought it was because it could not find the file, but when I inquire it, it has no problem finding it...

And as I said earlier, the AFILE contains only NaN value after the file has been read.

I am wondering if the problem lies in the .txt file or in the code. Maybe it is the READ statement, but the code seems ok to me.

I am kind of stuck at the moment and out of ideas... Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Code works fine for me. It reads the array, prints all the expected values, and doesn't hit `ierror` branch.

Comment: Try to add the end of line for your last line if it is missing.

Comment: you can/should trust the iostat value  -- there is no point to see what happens if you ignore it (ie by commenting out that code).  One possibility here is you have some acces/permission issue, example under windows the file is already open in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem when I ran a program on a Windows 2000, but it worked fine on a Windows 7 box.

In my situation, the application was built on a Win7 box using Intel Fortran V11. This application worked on a Win7 box, but when run on a Win2000 box it failed to read the first 2 entries.

Try compiling with the `/arch:IA32` option. This will use the X87 instruction set instead of the SSE2 enhanced instructions. This produces an application that works on both platforms.

Comment: this would be more suitable as comment

Comment: I agree, but I've only just signed up.  I get a warning that I must have at least "50 reputation" to add a comment to the original post.

Comment: Does my answer help with your issue? If not, consider asking a new question yourself with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the `PSR_FAB.txt` file is being opened at a position that is not the beginning of the file. Without specifying the `POSITION=` attribute to the `open` statement the file position is taken `ASIS`. I'm not certain what conditions result in `ASIS` yielding a position other than the start of the file, though.

I recommend specifying the file be rewound on opening, with:

```
 OPEN (UNIT = 1234 , FILE = 'PSR_FAB.txt', STATUS = 'OLD',     &
       ACTION = 'READ', POSITION = 'REWIND')
```

There are other issues that could cause this problem (or others like it), though.