# Unexpected end of file with the read command

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to read data from a mesh file in Fortran 2003, but I'm getting an unexpected end of file runtime error. Some lines in the file seem to be skipped by the read command. For example, with this sample.txt file :

```
      1   2   2   0       1    1132    1131    1165
      2   2   2   0       2    1099    1061    1060
```

I want to read the first integer from each line, so my program is :

```
program read_file
implicit none
  integer :: ierr, i, j
  open(unit=10,file='sample.txt',status='old',action='read',iostat=ierr) 
  read(10,*) i
  read(10,*) j
  write(*,*) i, j
end program read_file
```

And at runtime, I'm getting

```
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

What is odd is that if I force a carriage return at the end of the file, the program will read the two integers just fine.

Comment: Mhm, works for me (with both `gfortran` and `ifort`).

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I have encountered similar problems myself. The last line must be properly terminated.

Comment: I see... My editor (`vim`) does that for me ;-)

Comment: It may be quite well the same problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526117/f90-read-txt-file-return-nan as well.

Comment: On Windows, I have seen the same behavior with some compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to fix this on the read side (ie. properly terminating the last line of the file is not practical for some reason ) you might try reading each line into a string, then internal reading from the string:

```
 character*80 line
 integer i
 do ..
    read(unit,'(a)')line
    read(line,*)i
 enddo
```

Of course this may or may not work depending on the compiler as well..

Obviously fixing the file is the best option ( Whatever program is creating this file should be fixed )

Answer (score 0):

Every record in a sequential file must be properly terminated. The records in text files are the lines. They must be properly terminated. In some editors that means you must add an empty line to the end. Every line containing data must be terminated.

Some compilers are less sensitive to this issue than others and will terminate the last record for you.